# Call subprocess in python service

Tags: python, subprocess, call, os.system

I have a strange problem..
I've created a python script (modbus_sensor.py), which runs as a service.
Modbus_sensor.py calls around 15 other python scripts by a scheduler.

When I run modbus_sensor.py like: "python modbus_sensor.py" **it works fantastic** and all the sub scripts are running.
But when I start the script like a service: "service modbus_daemon start", the main script starts, but it doesn't call the other scripts.

```
def ExecuteReadChange(sScriptName = '', sArg1 = '', sArg2 = ''):
# os.system ('sudo python ' + sScriptName + ' ' + sArg1) #Call every script

# os.system ('sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/modbus_sensor/test.py') # returns 256
# subprocess.call('sudo python test.py', shell=True)
# subprocess.call('sudo /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/modbus_sensor/test.py', shell=True) # returns 1
```

I have tried everything like, with/without complete path.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide a start script of modbus_daemon (maybe problem is into the path to the python installation - try using full path to python)? Did you try to see output of service (best way is to use a logging package, but it can be done throw the stdout/stderr pipes like "/usr/bin/python modbus_sensor.py >> /tmp/modbus_sensor.log 2>&1")?

Comment: Hi Max, on top of every python script, I added: 
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# chkconfig: 2345 95 20

When i catch the result of
- os.system, it returns: 256
- subprocess.call, it returns: 1

Comment: The logs contains nothing.. 
When i run manual with 'python modbus_sensor.py', it contains prints of the scripts.
When running by daemon, it does not contain anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to disable **requiretty** in your /etc/sudoers settings:

Use the `visudo` command to edit `/etc/sudoers`

Replace:

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

With:

```
Defaults    !requiretty
```

Comment: Hi jlyuong, thanks for your anwser, i've just tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: Jlyoung, wow, actually it did work, but after reboot i've tested wrong. 
Thanks for your help.. :)